# music not looping with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, audio, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

In my "initWithSize" in my main menu implementation file I put in code to play music. I have a loading screen pop up and then the main menu scene loads in. When the loading screen pops up it starts playing music but the loading screen never goes away and I want the music to loop and it's not looping. I don't really know what's going on here.

```
    NSError *error;
    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"POL-parallel-fields-short" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];
    [player setVolume:0.1];
    [player prepareToPlay];

    SKAction*   playAction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [player play];
        }];
    SKAction *playMusic = [SKAction repeatActionForever:playAction];

[self runAction:playMusic];
```

Comment: I dont understand well. [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[playAction, [SKAction waitForDuration:musicTime]]]]; try this maybe this will works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that your method of 'looping' is correct...

You don't need to create an action for that,
Just try changing your code to this-

```
NSError *error;  
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"POL-parallel-fields-short" withExtension:@"mp3"];  
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];  
[player setVolume:0.1];  
[player prepareToPlay];  
player.numberOfLoops = -1;  
[player play];
```

`numberOfLoops` is a property that set the number of loops the audio will play.
From apple's documentation- 0 is the default, that will play the audio once.
Any positive number will set the number of times it'll be played.
Any negative number will cause the music to loop indefinitely, until `stop` is explicitly called.

I have no idea why your loading screen is not going away,
Since you haven't included any code that relates to it.

But the above will solve your music issue mate.

Comment: Thank you! For the loading screen there is no code that relates to it because Xcode does that automatically.

Comment: Ohh...I thought you were creating a custom loading screen...You mean it stuck at the splash screen at the beginning of the app? Is it happens both on simulator and on device? I read someplace on someone complaining about the same issue, and later he found out that his app was stuck in an infinite loop before showing the first view. Could you check your code to see that is not the case here as well?

Comment: I just tried making it not loop and it still had the same problem. So when I start my app the launch image pops up and music starts playing. Then nothing else happens, it stays on the launch image and if i put the music to loop it keeps going if I put no loop it finishes playing and still nothing happens.

Comment: As I've mentioned, someone else who encountered the same issue found out he accidentaly created infinite loop before the view appeared, which caused the app to be stuck at the splash screen. Could you check the code that initially runs. you probablly should focus on `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`

Comment: The above is all your `initWithSize` method? I would also suggest placing Breakpoints to make sure you aren't stuck in a loop someplace...